# Working with Core Data Relationship and segues

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app I'm trying to show the dates of a particular medicine which i pass through `prepareForSegue`. Than i'd like to prepare an array containing dates associated only with medicine name i pass. How to prepare fetch like this ?

My models:

```
extension Dates {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate?
@NSManaged var takes: Medicine?

}

extension Medicine {

@NSManaged var amount: String?
@NSManaged var endDate: String?
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var time: String?
@NSManaged var notificationSet: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var taken: NSOrderedSet?

}
```

In viewDidLoad i try to prepare this array like this:

```
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let fetchRequestDate = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Dates")
let fetchRequestMedicine = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Medicine")


var medicine : Medicine?

var dates = [NSDate]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {

        fetchRequestDate.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "takes.name == %@ ", medicine!.name!)

        let resultsDates  = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestDate)

        for date in resultsDates {
            print(date)
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.userInfo)
    }
```

To use it later in this function:

```
func calendar(calendar: CKCalendarView!, configureDateItem dateItem: CKDateItem!, forDate date: NSDate!) {

    for dateTaken in dates {
        if calendar.date(date, isSameDayAsDate: dateTaken) {
            dateItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of your previous question. Apply predicates to fetch requests before executing them. You don't say what your code is doing wrong - show example data.

Comment: Now i'm fetching all `dates` from `CoreData`. How to connect (maybe with predicates) this particular medicine passed through segue with it's dates ?

Comment: Apply the predicate before you execute, then use the date relationship rather than a fetch (or set a predicate on the date fetch to limit the medicine).

Comment: I tried to use the predicate like this:
`fetchRequestDate.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "takes.name == %@ ", medicine!.name!)` , but it throws uncaught exception that takes.name is not found in entity

Comment: Because the predicate is written to be on date but you set it on medicine

Comment: I updated my code, but it's still can't find this this entity

Comment: What do you mean? You have a good list of dates now?

Comment: No. It is throwing the same error: uncaught exception that takes.name is not found in entity